# Quectel MC65 GPS fail(empty response)

Tags: arduino, gps, gsm, at-command, quectel

I am using Quectel's MC65 to get location info.

Here is my at command process:

1-`AT+QGNSSC=1\r`

2-`AT+QGNSSRD=\"NMEA/RMC\"\r"`

The GNSS powers up correctly but I only get `+QGNSSRD: OK` in response!

[image: serial response in PUTTY]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had connected the GNSS and AUX communication ports wrong.
It should be

GNSS_RX--->AUX_TX

and

GNSS_TX--->AUX_RX(I am using ALL_IN_ONE mode).

It's sort of common sense and it's a bad mistake but this might help someone debug his/her system.